# Parsing a JSON Object in Java having special characters

Tags: java, json, parsing

I am stuck in a situation, where my `JSONString` (**ruleFormJSONString**) looks like :

```
{
"ruleDescription":"Test Rule2 Description",
"urlId":"1",
"listOfBusinessdays":["1","2","5","6","7"],
"status":"1",
"hierarchyId":"3",
"fromTime":"08:00",
"toTime":"18:00",
"dcnid":"1",
"eventId":"1",
"rowstate":"1",
"listOfLocations":["ASM","DEL"],
"ruleName":"Test Rule2",
"ruleId":"7","msgId":"1"
}
```

As you can see there are 2 attributes named `fromTime` and `toTime` which has a `:`

So while parsing this in Java, I used

```
JSONObject  ruleFormJSON    =   JSONObject.fromString(ruleFormJSONString);
String      fromTime        =   (String)ruleFormJSON.getString("fromTime");
String      toTime          =   (String)ruleFormJSON.getString("toTime");
```

I am getting a `NumberFormatException` which is

**java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "18:00"**

So please suggest me how, to get the value in the corresponding `String` variable.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you use `Integer.parseInt()`? Please post relevant code.

Comment: @Srinivas How can the value, which is `18:00` be parse by Integer.parseInt and stored in an Integer?

Comment: `getString()` in `JSONObject` doesn't throw `NumberFormatException`? Hence the question.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: I don't know why it would cause your issue but you do not need to cast a string to a string `(string)ruleFormJSON.getString("fromTime");`

Comment: I am sure you did not get the NFE from the lines you pasted. Must be somewhere else.

Comment: I agree with Henry: The JSON and the code you have posted will not throw a NumberFormatException. Please better investigate where the exception occurs and post the relevant code.

Comment: The only doubt I have about this problem is related to the format of the string 18:00, which in json usually is the pairs with the ':' character separating the key and the value. May be your json library have a bug?

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is an error on this line:

```
"listOfBusinessdays":"1","2","5","6","7"],
```

A closed bracket square but no open bracket before.
May be this hang up the parser.

Comment: Sorry Freedev, it was my mistake while writing the question, have edited my question please check